# cuda workflow - possible scenario

Tags: cuda

The GeForce GTX 560 Ti has 8 SM and each SM has 48 cuda cores (SP). I'm going to launch kernel in this way: **kernel<<<1024,1024>>>** The SM schedules threads in groups of 32 parallel threads called warps. How will blocks and threads be distributed between 8 SM and 48 SP in each SM ? We have 1024 blocks and 1024 threads so what is possible scenario ? What is the maximum number of threads executing literally at the same time ? What is difference between fermi dual warp scheduler and earlier schedulers ?

Answer (score 1):

The NVIDIA supplied occupancy calculator spreadsheet, which ships in every SDK or is available for download [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls), can provide the answer to the first three "sub-questions" you have asked.

As for the difference between multiprocessor level scheduling in Fermi compared with earlier architectures, the name ("dual warp scheduler") really says it all. In Fermi, MPs retire instructions from two warps simultaneously, compared to a single warp, as was the case in the first two generations of CUDA capable architectures. If you want a more detailed answer than that, I recommend reading the Fermi architecture whitepaper, available for download [here](http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/fermi_white_papers/NVIDIA_Fermi_Compute_Architecture_Whitepaper.pdf).

Comment: threads per SM = 1536  First step: each SM get only one block (1024 threads)because two blocks per SM exceed threads per SM, next 1024 threads on SM's are divided into 32 warps (each warp has 32 threads, 32 x 32 = 1024) and distrbuted between 32 SP(each SP execute one warp) On each SM 16 SP's remain idle !? Next steps look like above...?

Comment: No that is not how it works. I think you should (re)read the first few chapters of the CUDA programming guide to understand the execution model and then look at the material I linked to.

Comment: The most important information which I dismissed: each SP is pipelined and execute 1 thread but with 4 clocks of latency so one warp (32 threads) needs 8 SP's to be execute. These 4 clocks of latency refer to floating point and integer operations performs by a thread, but what about SFU operations and double precision ? How the latency refer to the kernel complexity ?

Comment: Again, no. That applies to the GT200 and G80/90 architectures, not the Fermi GPU you are asking about.

Comment: Ok, but what about those latencies mentioned above ?

Comment: For the second time, they apply to the G80/G200 architecture where each SM has 8 cores. They are irrelevant to the Fermi GPU you are asking about. For an overview of how these architectures really work, see [this](http://www.realworldtech.com/page.cfm?ArticleID=RWT090808195242) for the GT200 and [this](http://www.realworldtech.com/page.cfm?ArticleID=RWT093009110932) for Fermi.